# Forms of interaction between two spins

Tags: symmetry, quantum-spin, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am learning the principles of nuclear magnetic resonance, and came across the interaction between two Hydrogen nuclear spins, which affects the relaxation properties of materials like water in NMR. Suppose we have 2 spins, ${\bf S}_1$ at $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and ${\bf S}_2$ at $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. Then the dipolar interaction Hamiltonian was given the form

$H \sim {\bf S}_1 \cdot {\bf S}_2 - 3 ({\bf S}_1\cdot{\bf r}_{12})({\bf S}_2\cdot{\bf r}_{12})/r^2_{12}$.

Here ${\bf r}_{12} = (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, z_2-z_1)$. The $\mu_0$, $\hbar$, $1/{r^3_{12}}$ and numerical factors are omitted.

My questions is that, if we write this Hamiltonian in the the matrix form

$H=S_{1,i}D_{ij}S_{2,j}$,

Then we found the D matrix is traceless. What is the physical or symmetry reason for this? And could we derive all possible forms of spin-spin interactions from physics or symmetry principles?

Thank you!